# Get 24 hour format time from 12 hour format time in MySQL / Read 12 hour format string into time so I can convert it to another time

Tags: mysql

I'm on this page now reading documentation...
[Data time function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)
for this

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT("9:45 PM", "%H:%i:%s")
```

Result what I get

```
09:45:00
```

I think what should I get is

```
21:45:00
```

How to achieve this? I am on the documentation page but not getting anything.
Maybe I should say how do I read the string "9:45 PM" into time and make it in a time and then convert it to what I want?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```sql
SELECT STR_TO_DATE('09:45 PM', '%h:%i %p');
```

Or

```
SELECT TIME_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('09:45 PM', '%h:%i %p'), '%T');
```

<kbd>[SQL Fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/d41d8/1170)</kbd>

Check:

- [STR_TO_DATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date)
- [TIME_FORMAT](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_time-format)

Comment: SELECT TIME_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE("9:45 PM",'%h:%i %p'), "%H:%i:%s")

Answer (score 1):

try with this

```
use DATE_FORMAT()
```

and use %T to get 24 hours format......hope this link will be usefull for you http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: SELECT DATE_FORMAT("9:45 PM"," %T") is not working...  may be i should change my question to read string into time..

Comment: yes...make according to that you will get...all the best

Answer (score -1):

Refer [date](http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_date_date.asp) function

```
$RetStr = date("H:i:s", strtotime($time));
```

Comment: It is better to add some explanation and avoid code-only answers.

Comment: sry i do not need php solution... i want a solution which have mysql.. beacuse i want to retrive data on the basis of the value./.