# How to load CSV data into MYSQL to get a TIME datatype in 24 HR format

Tags: mysql, datetime, str-to-date

I am trying to load data from a csv file into MYSQL. One of the columns in the csv table contains data related to time. The data is stored in the column titled Issue_Time with time values such as as 07:30A and 01:35P, where A and P represent AM and PM. The problem I have is that I cannot get the data to load into MYSQL in a format where I can get both the AM and PM times as a TIME data type or in 24 hr format.

I first tried loading the data in MYSQL using the TIME data type. I was only able to get the data to load by first using this code.

```
SET @@SESSION.sql_mode='ALLOW_INVALID_DATES';
```

When the data loaded, the data were transformed to time format with times as 07:30:00 and 01:35:00. The problem with this is that the AM and PM are no longer represented. I therefore now just have times between 00:00:00 and 12:59:00. I tried to convert this to 24Hr form using code

```
UPDATE my_table SET Issue_Time = TIME_FORMAT(Issue_Time, '%H:%i:%s')
```

but this did not work.

I also tried loading the data first as VARCHAR(255) and then converting to TIME using

```
UPDATE my_table SET Issue_Time = STR_TO_DATE(Issue_Time, '%H:%i%p')
```

This resulted in a column of NULL values being loaded.

Can someone help me get the data into MYSQL in either 24 Hr time format ( such as, 13:35:00) or in a form where I will be able to tell the times AM from PM? Thanks.

Comment: It could possibly by 2 process first update time column form 7.30A to 7.30AM by using REPLACE query  thereafter you can convert time column  as u wish... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7734077/mysql-replace-character-in-columns    and  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27857099/get-24-hour-format-time-from-12-hour-format-time-in-mysql-read-12-hour-format

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your are using `LOAD DATA INFILE` to import your CSV, you can use [Input Preprocessing](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/load-data.html#load-data-input-preprocessing) to format the incoming time value with [STR_TO_DATE()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date). And because you only have the `A` and `P` after the time, we will [CONCAT()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) to add the missing `M`. We don't know the structure of your file or table, so here is an example:

```sql
LOAD DATA INFILE 'data.csv' INTO TABLE my_table
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
IGNORE 1 LINES
    (id, name, @time)
    SET Issue_Time = STR_TO_DATE(CONCAT(@time, 'M'), '%h:%i%p')
```